# how to get string using webview and intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, webview

i'm trying to get string using intent and webview but that string that show just one string like `xc_info` but I want to show all the strings.

here's my string :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="xc_info">Dirancang untuk lintas alam ringan hingga sedang. Didesain agar efisien dan optimal pada saat mengayuh dan menanjak di jalan aspal hingga jalan tanah pedesaan. Sangat disarankan bagi pemula yang ingin memulai bermain MTB.</string>
    <string name="am_info">Dirancang untuk lintas alam berat seperti naik turun bukit, masuk hutan, melintasi medan berbatu, dan menjelajah medan offroad jarak jauh. Keunggulan all mountain ada pada ketahanan dan kenyamanannya untuk dikendarai. Namun kurang efisien dipakai pada medan tanjakan yang panjang dan curam. Hampir semua sepeda AM bertipe full-suspension.</string>
    <string name="fr_info">Dirancang untuk mampu bertahan menghadapi drop off (lompatan) tinggi dan kondisi ekstrim sejenisnya. Bodinya kuat namun tidak secepat dan selincah all mountain karena bobotnya yang lebih berat. Kurang cocok untuk dipakai jarak jauh dan sangat tidak cocok untuk tanjakan.</string>
    <string name="dh_info">Dirancang agar dapat melaju cepat, aman dan nyaman dalam menuruni bukit dan gunung. Mampu menikung dengan stabil pada kecepatan tinggi dan selalu dilengkapi suspensi belakang untuk meredam benturan yang sering terjadi. Sepeda DH tidak mengutamakan kenyaman mengayuh karena hanya dipakai untuk turun gunung. Sepeda downhill juga lebih mengacu pada lomba, sehingga yang menjadi titik tekan dalam perancangannya adalah bagaimana agar kuat namun dapat melaju dengan cepat. Untuk menuju ke lokasi, para downhiller tidak mengayuh sepeda mereka namun diangkut dengan mobil. Tidak efisien dipergunakan di dalam kota maupun di jalur cross country.</string>
    <string name="dj_info">Nama lainnya adalah trial atau urban MTB. Sepeda jenis ini awalnya didesain untuk anak muda perkotaan yang menggunakan sepeda gunung selain sebagai alat transportasi, ngebut di jalanan kota, juga digunakan untuk melakukan atraksi lompatan tinggi dan ekstrim. Fungsinya mirip BMX namun dengan bentuk yang diperbesar.</string>
    <string name="rb_info">Road Bike lebih akrab dikenal dengan sepeda balap, dengan bentuknya yang khas dan fungsinya lebih untuk medan jalan aspal (road). Road Bike merupakan tipe sepeda yang dikhususkan untuk balapan dijalanan dan dirancang sedemikian mungkin untuk cepat. Dengan ban yang tipis Road Bike melaju cepat dan dengan bantuan pengaturan gigi, Road Bike bisa melaju dengan sangat cepat.</string>

</resources>
```

and here's my activity to call vebview using intent:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent(Tab_Brand_ListView_Activity.this, Tab_Bike_Information_Activity.class);
    switch (item) {
        case 0:
            intent.putExtra("text", items);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 1:
            intent.putExtra("text", items);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 2:
            intent.putExtra("text", items);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 3:
            intent.putExtra("text", items);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 4:
            intent.putExtra("text", items);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case 5:
            intent.putExtra("text", items);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
```

what i want is show all the strings but in fact the string just show one string. how do i get appropriate string when I click on the list that I want?
thanks a lot.

here's the logcat :

```
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wilis.hellotabwidget/com.wilis.hellotabwidget.Tab_Bike_Information_Activity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1976)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1871)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1828)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1808)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at com.wilis.hellotabwidget.Tab_Bike_Information_Activity.onCreate(Tab_Bike_Information_Activity.java:32)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
09-19 12:15:59.889: E/AndroidRuntime(2611):     ... 11 more
```

here's my activity :

```
public class Tab_Bike_Information_Activity extends Activity {
WebView mWebView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_bike_information);

    final ActionBar actionBar = (ActionBar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
    actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

    int index = getIntent().getIntExtra("text", 0);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    String temp = "<html><body>" + "<p align=\"justify\">"
            + getString(R.string.xc_info + index) + "</p> " + "</body></html>";
    mWebView.loadData(temp, "text/html", "utf-8"); 
        mWebView.addView(mWebView);


}
```

and it's my manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.wilis.hellotabwidget"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen_Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Home_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Tab_Bike_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Tab_Bike_Information_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Tab_Shop_Repair_ListView_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListViewActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Tab_Brand_ListView_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".BikeType_ListView_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".search_activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Tab_Information_Activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".coba_activity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Home_Gridview"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: make array and map the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write below Code line in all case statement and only change String Name in `R.string.xc_info` .

```
intent.putExtra("text", getResources().getString(R.string.xc_info));
```

instead of

```
intent.putExtra("text", items);
```

Comment: @RichardoLuis Please post your full error logcat in your question.

Comment: @RichardoLuis Post your both activity code and manifest file code because there is some other problems in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In your onClick method you put a integer into intent, but you try to get a string, that's incorrect.

```
intent.putExtra("text", items);
String temp = getIntent().getExtras().getString("text");
```

I think you want to get different string from the intent when user click each item.
You can do it like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_bike_information);

    final ActionBar actionBar = (ActionBar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
    actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

    Int index = getIntent().getIntExtra("text", 0);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    String temp = "<html><body>" + "<p align=\"justify\">"
        + getString(R.string.xc_info + index) + "</p> " + "</body></html>";
    mWebView.loadData(temp, "text/html", "utf-8"); 
    //mWebView.addView(mWebView);
}
```

Comment: Oh, man, I just notice that you add mWebView to itself..., you can just comment it out, it's useless.

Comment: Look at this line in logcat [Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.]

Comment: Your webView is already have a layout parent in your XML file, and at the last line, you try to add it to another view, a child view could  only have one parent view. So the system throw you a java.lang.IllegalStateException.

Comment: thanks @cinsondev i'm so stupid, it's work, but same problem here,, it's just show one string,, when i click on diferent index, it's just show `xc_info` all the time when i click on other index. can u tell me why?

Comment: it's always show `<string name="xc_info">Dirancang untuk lintas alam ringan hingga sedang. Didesain agar efisien dan optimal pada saat mengayuh dan menanjak di jalan aspal hingga jalan tanah pedesaan. Sangat disarankan bagi pemula yang ingin memulai bermain MTB.</string>` but what i want is show other string based of each index.

Comment: sorry ,I just attended a meeting. Are you sure you added the index to string id like this? getString(R.string.xc_info + index), you can print out the value of index.

Comment: yeah i'm sure, i've done like u said, but it's still show `xc_info`

Comment: what do you mean? i don't get it. i'm sorry, i'm new on android developer

Comment: you can add Log.v("debug", "index = "+index); after int index = getIntent().getIntExtra("text", 0); and check the value of index in logcat